# Detecting scam tokens on bsc pancakeswap

Tags: security, bsc, scam

Certain contracts cannot be sold after buying on pancake swap apparently because they have code that makes that so.

This is one example:

0x6d041ae2494641c229e9e348616f40bf390aa3f8

How is it that token creators manage to make this happen, and is there a way/service to detect it on a token besides buying and selling a small amount?

The sell tx will fail on pancake with error: "Unexpected issue with estimating the gas.Please try again."

I tried modifying the amount decimals and increasing slippage to max as suggested online but this doesn't seem to be that issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a **honeypot**. There are service that are able to detect if a token is a honeypot, such as https://honeypot.is/.

Honeypotting can easily be achieved by manipulating the beforeTransfer or transfer function to not allow transfers from a specific addresses. You should therefore always do due diligence before buying a token.